# How to assign the records of an array to a parameter in REST request body?

Tags: python, arrays, rest, dictionary

I have the following array in Python:

```
[
 {'type': 'A1'},
 {
   'filter': {
      'type': 'A2',
      'data': [{'key': 'name_1', 'value': 'a'}, {'key': 'name_2', 'value': 'a'}]
   }
 },
 {
   'filter': {
      'type': 'A2',
      'data': [{'key': 'name_1', 'value': 'b'}, {'key': 'name_2', 'value': 'b'}]
   }
 }
]
```

I need to assign this array to a **parameter** called `constraints` in the REST request body:

```
constraints = {
  'type': 'A1',
  'filter': {
      'type': 'A2',
      'data': [{'key': 'name_1', 'value': 'a'}, {'key': 'name_2', 'value': 'a'}]
  },
  'filter': {
      'type': 'A2',
      'data': [{'key': 'name_1', 'value': 'b'}, {'key': 'name_2', 'value': 'b'}]
  }
}
```

Comment: something like `json.dump({'contraints': your_list}, your_file_descriptor, indent=1)`?

Comment: Which language are you planning to use? Also note that the value of 'constraints' in the second JSON example you provided is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @FedericoDiCesare I am using Python. Regarding the JSON, yes, it's just 1 parameter in a JSON file.

Comment: @mozway: What is "your_file_descriptor"?

Comment: for example: `json.dump({'contraints': l}, open('test.json', 'w'), indent=1)`

Comment: In python you can simply use dictionaries: something like ```my_dict['constraints'] = my_list``` will do the trick.
In the second JSON example you need square brackets: ```constraints: [ {}, {}, ... ]```

Comment: @mozway: Ok, I see. But it writes `{'constraints': [...]}` instead of `{'constraints': {...}}`

Comment: @FedericoDiCesare: Yes, but I need to substitute `[` by `{` to get `'constraints': {...}` and not `'constraints': [...]`, and i dont' know how to do it correctly

Comment: What you want doesn't seem to be valid json

Comment: @Fluxy you cannot have a list of { } enclosed in other { }. You need square brackets to list many json objects.

Comment: @FedericoDiCesare: You are completely right. My bad. The target is not a JSON string. I rather need assigning values to a parameter in the REST request body. The problem is that the keys are duplicated, i.e. `filter`. This the dictionary data structure would not fit. I updated my question. Apologies.

Comment: @Fluxy What exactly is the "REST request body"? That is not a well-defined format that I know of. It is still unclear what it is you actually want. Please think about it more and update your question as it does not make any sense in its current form.

Comment: @Fluxy I see you edited your question again, but still did not provide any actual code, where you would use your new `constraints` variable. It now looks like you want it to be a dictionary, but have _duplicate_ keys somehow? Your way of "asking a question" is very inconsiderate. Maybe someone else has the patience for this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a **list**:

```py
variable = [...]
```

A list of dictionaries, in your specific case.

Your desired output is not valid JSON. The supposed value to the key `"constraints"` **must** be enclosed in `[]`. These here `{}` enclose key-value pairs.

If all you want to do, is have a JSON file with one key-value pair of `{"constraints": [...]}`, you can do this:

```py
import json

variable = [...]

with open("your_file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump({"constraints": variable}, f, indent=2)
```

**PS:**

You should probably check [this](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) out, since you seem to be confused about what JSON looks like. Quote:

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` and ends with `]`. Values are separated by `,`.